# Json_encode strange behavior

Tags: php, json

I am experiencing some strange behavior when using json_encode.
This is my code:

```
if($_POST["action"] == 'profile')
{
    sleep(2);

    $error = '';

    $success = '';

    $admin_name = '';

    $admin_contact_no = '';

    $admin_email = '';

    $admin_profile = '';

    $data = array(
        ':admin_email'  =>  $_POST["admin_email"],
        ':admin_id'     =>  $_POST['hidden_id']
    );

    $visitor->query = "
    SELECT * FROM admin_table 
    WHERE admin_email = :admin_email 
    AND admin_id != :admin_id
    ";

    $visitor->execute($data);

    if($visitor->row_count() > 0)
    {
        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">User Email Already Exists</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        $user_image = $_POST["hidden_user_image"];
        if($_FILES["user_image"]["name"] != '')
        {
            $user_image = upload_image();
        }

        $admin_name = $visitor->clean_input($_POST["admin_name"]);

        $admin_contact_no = $_POST["admin_contact_no"];

        $admin_email = $_POST["admin_email"];

        $admin_profile = $user_image;

        $data = array(
            ':admin_name'       =>  $admin_name,
            ':admin_contact_no' =>  $admin_contact_no,
            ':admin_email'      =>  $admin_email,
            ':admin_profile'    =>  $admin_profile
        );

        $visitor->query = "
        UPDATE admin_table 
        SET admin_name = :admin_name, 
        admin_contact_no = :admin_contact_no, 
        admin_email = :admin_email,  
        admin_profile = :admin_profile 
        WHERE admin_id = '".$_POST['hidden_id']."'
        ";

        $visitor->execute($data);

        $success = '<div class="alert alert-success">User Details Updated</div>';
    }

    $output = array(
        'error'     =>  $error,
        'success'   =>  $success,
        'admin_name'    =>  $admin_name,
        'admin_contact_no'  =>  $admin_contact_no,
        'admin_email'   =>  $admin_email,
        'admin_profile' =>  $admin_profile
    );

    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Alert message for `$error` displays accordingly while alert message for `$success` does not.
If I swap positions between `$error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">User Email Already Exists</div>';` and `$success = '<div class="alert alert-success">User Details Updated</div>';`, `$error` still works while `$success` still does not, which deeply confuses me.
I know I can avoid all this trouble by using `echo`, but I really want to find out what the issue is here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you mean that you've ascertained that the `UPDATE` works, but that the output from `json_encode()` does _not_ contain a value for the `success` key?

Comment: It may depend on what you do with the data on the "view", maybe the issue is there and not in this part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a spelling error, wrote "succes" instead of "success".

I apologize for the trouble and thank you for your help.

Comment: This is how you shoot yourself in foot with dynamic languages